# scala: "block cannot contain declarations" in match case

Tags: scala

I have the following function which gives me the error:  block cannot contain declarations
What is wrong with this code?

```
def max[A](tree: Tree[A])(func: (A, A) => Int): A = tree match {
    case Leaf(value) => value
    case Branch(value, left, right) => {
      val leftMax = max(left)(func)
      val rightMax = max(right)(func)
      var currMax: A // block cannot contain declarations
      if (func(leftMax, rightMax) > 0) {
        currMax = leftMax
      } else {
        currMax = rightMax
      }

      if (func(value, currMax) > 0) {
        currMax = value
      }
      currMax
    }
}
```

Comment: just for sanity: brackets in case statements are not necessary:`case Branch(value, left, right) =>  //multiline statement here`

Answer (score 4):

At the line where you have the compilation error you're missing an assignment.

You have to explicitly assign it a `null` value:

```
var currMax: A = null.asInstanceOf[A]
```

Note that `asInstanceOf` is not an actual method call, so this code will not cause a `NullPointerException`.

What the compiler is trying to tell you is that the syntax you are using is reserved for declarations (in particular of abstract members), as in the following example:

```
trait SomeTrait[A] {
  def someMember: A
}
```

I'd still recommend to avoid initializing mutable state to a `null` value though, unless strictly necessary. You can do that with the following code:

```
def max[A](tree: Tree[A])(func: (A, A) => Int): A = tree match {
  case Leaf(value) => value
  case Branch(value, left, right) => {
    val leftMax = max(left)(func)
    val rightMax = max(right)(func)
    val maxBranch = if (func(leftMax, rightMax) > 0) leftMax else rightMax
    if (func(value, maxBranch) > 0) value else maxBranch
  }
}
```

Note that in Scala, `if`/`else` is an expression (i.e. it returns a value) and the last value evaluated in a method is the returned value for that method, so the either `leftMax`, `value` or `rightMax` will be returned, depending on how the conditions will be evaluated.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the difference between **declaration** and **definition**

```
var x: Int       // declaration: variable named x is of type Int
var x: Int = 42  // definition:  variable named x is of type Int and refers to value 42
```

Note how pure declaration simply states the type of the variable but says nothing about its value. On the other hand, definition is both a declaration **and** it associates a concrete value with the variable. We could have pure declarations within traits or abstract classes, for example,

```
trait Foo {
  var x: Int // pure declaration
}

object MyFoo extends Foo {
  override var x: Int = 42
}
```

however we cannot have them inside block expressions, for example

```
{
  var x: Int    // error: only traits and abstract classes can have declared but undefined members
  "hello world"
}
```

Illustrating the difference between declaration and definition, consider what happens at bytecode level when we declare a variable `x`

```
scala> trait Foo { val x: Int }
defined trait Foo

scala> :javap -c -filter Foo
Compiled from "<console>"
public interface Foo {
  public abstract int x();
}
```

versus when we define the variable `x`

```
scala> trait Foo { val x: Int = 42 }
defined trait Foo

scala> :javap -c -filter Foo
Compiled from "<console>"
public interface Foo {
  public abstract void $line4$$read$Foo$_setter_$x_$eq(int);

  public abstract int x();

  public static void $init$(Foo);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: bipush        42
       3: invokeinterface #23,  2           // InterfaceMethod $line4$$read$Foo$_setter_$x_$eq:(I)V
       8: return
}
```

Note how in the case of declaration there were **no** code instructions generated, whilst in the case of definition there are actual instructions such as `bipush 42`. Hence declaration would be something of interest just to the compiler, whilst definition also results in concrete runtime memory manipulations.